# Swiftで関数の実行結果を別ファイルの変数に渡したい。

Tags: swift

Parseを使ってデータをやり取りする実装を行っていますが、2点ご質問があります。
目的：clip classを作成し、別の値を返し、成功を取得したい。

1. `return clipObjects` で、`[PFObject] is not convertible to "Void"` というエラーが起きる理由
2. backgroundで処理しているので、成功時に処理をするというクロージャの書き方

```swift
class Clip {

    class var sharedInstance : Clip {
        struct Static {
            static let instance : Clip = Clip()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    func apiCall() {
        var currentUser:PFUser! = PFUser.currentUser()
        var clip = PFObject(className: "Clip")
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Clip")        
        query.whereKey("user", equalTo: currentUser.username!)        
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{ (objects,error) -> Void in

            if let clipObjects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                println("clipObjects ------------------ \(clipObjects)")
                return clipObjects
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewController

```
class ViewController : UIViewController{
    var clipData : [PFObject] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var clip = Clip.sharedInstance

        var clipData = clip.apiCall()
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        clip.apiCall{(success:[AnyObject]?,data:[AnyObject]?) -> Void in
               // clip classから渡ってきたデータをself.clipDataに入れたい
               self.clipData = data
               self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

以上ですが、アドバイスいただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. エラーが起きる理由

これはapiCall()の宣言で、戻り値が指定されていないのが原因です。エラーを解消するためには、次のようになると思われます。

```
func apiCall() -> [PFObject]? {

    // 省略

}
```

そもそも、引数の型も書かれてないので、その部分でもエラーになってそうですが。

#### 2. 成功時に処理をする

これは単純に、成功時に処理したいクロージャを渡すだけで問題ないかと思われます。

#### まとめ

上記の2つの問題点を考えると、こんな感じになるかと思います。

apiCall()の実装

```
func apiCall(finish: ((objects:[AnyObject]!, error: NSError!)->Void)) {

    // 何らかの処理

    // 終了時、クロージャを呼び出し
    finish(objects: objects, error: error)
}
```

apiCall()の呼び出し側

```
apiCall() { objects, error in

    // 終了時に呼ばれるクロージャ
    // 別スレッドから呼ばれる場合、GUIの操作はメインスレッドで

}
```

apiCall()から呼ばれるクロージャで処理が完結するため、結果的に戻り値は不要になってます。